# Wordpress loop running out of posts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm confused as to what is happening here, I have 11 posts, with 3 initially loaded and 3 that load every time I scroll to the bottom of the page until all 11 are shown. This is fine.

The problem occurs when I click a button and dynamically load the first 3 posts onto the page again. This loaded via .html(data).

I'm doing this on a "page" called archives.

It's as though the archive page knows I displayed all 11 posts before and refuses to start again unless I refresh the page.

How do I reset the loop, or tell wordpress that I want to start from the 3rd post again?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("a.sort-all").bind("click", function(e) {
        load_posts(this);
        e.preventDefault();                 
    });

    function load_posts() {
        var ajax_url = $('.sort-all').attr('data-all-url');
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "HTML",
            url: ajax_url,
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                action: 'data_click_all',
                offset: offset
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });

    }

    var ajax_url = $('.sort-all').attr('data-all-url');
    var offset = 0;
    $('#content').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if(direction === 'down'){
            offset = parseInt(offset) + 3;
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "HTML",
                url: ajax_url,
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    action: 'data_scroll_all',
                    offset: offset
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#content').append(data);
                    $.waypoints('refresh');
                }
            });
        }
    }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
    });
}); 

if (!class_exists('load_posts')) {
    class load_posts    {
        /**
        * PHP 4 Compatible Constructor
        */
        function load_posts(){$this->__construct();}
        /**
        * PHP 5 Constructor
            */      
        function __construct(){
            add_action('wp_ajax_data_scroll_all', array(&$this, 'data_scroll_all'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_scroll_all', array(&$this, 'data_scroll_all'));
            //----//
            add_action('wp_ajax_data_click_all', array(&$this, 'data_click_all'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_click_all', array(&$this, 'data_click_all'));
        }

        function data_click_all(){
            global $post;
            $offset = $_POST['offset'];
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__not_in' => 1,'orderby' => 'date');
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part( 'content-archive' );
            } wp_reset_query();
            die('');
        }

        function data_scroll_all(){
            global $post;
            $offset = $_POST['offset'];
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'category__not_in' => 1, 'offset' => $offset, 'orderby' => 'date');
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part( 'content-archive' );
            } wp_reset_query();
            die('');
        }


    }
}
if (class_exists('load_posts')) {
    $newload_posts = new load_posts();
}
```

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: i heard that if you really whish it, wordpress will listen to you. Seriously, we dont have any code, we dont know if the counter is in a local js var or in the serverside or how do you deal with it, and how the calls to retrieve more posts are done, and who is handling them in the server

Comment: @CarlosRobles I've added some code. The reason I didn't add code the first time was because it seemed to be some Loop logic that I was missing and just needed explained to me. Like I could bind some kind of click event that resets the wordpress loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click a button and dynamically load the first 3 posts onto the page again, You have to reset the variable offset.  Also refresh the waypoints.

```
 $("a.sort-all").bind("click", function(e) {
         offset=0;
         load_posts(this);
        $.waypoints('refresh');
        e.preventDefault();                 
    });
```

if it doesnt work, proably you dont have an error with the number of posts, but another error that prevents everything to work.

please, add an alert when you enter the waypoint

```
$('#content').waypoint(function(direction) {
      alert("current: "+offset);
///...
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and it still doesn't work, say if I reload the page and scroll once so it loads another 3 posts and click the ajax button, it loads the original 3 posts into the container again but it's as though it no longer recognises the waypoints.

Comment: So yea, something is definitely wrong with the waypoints, when click the ajax button the alert no longer works.

Comment: ahhhhh I fixed it I didn't add $.waypoints('refresh'); to the click event ajax success... damn it. Thank you for your help.